# Vertically centering a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div which is inside another div.

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I am currently using.

```
    #outerDiv {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #innerDiv {
        width: 284px;
        height: 290px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -147px;
        margin-left: -144px;
    }
```

As you can see, the approach I use now depends on the width and height of `#innerDiv`. If the width/height changes, I will have to modify the `margin-top` and `margin-left` values. Is there any generic solution that I can use to center the `#innerDiv` independently of its size?

I figured out that using `margin: auto` can horizontally align the `#innerDiv` to the middle. But what about vertical alignment?

Comment: what if you do margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k6ShD/4/

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Comment: Suggestion given by others are right. Just to add.
If u have parent div called DivParent and child div called ChildDiv, then
Just add margin: auto to child div, this will make childDiv or innerDiv in center to ParentDiv.

Answer (score 959, accepted):

[**tl;dr**](http://codepen.io/meodai/pen/XbEqZw?editors=010)

Vertical align middle works, but you will have to use `table-cell` on your parent element and `inline-block` on the child.

This solution is not going to work in IE6 & 7. 
Yours is the safer way to go for those. 
But since you tagged your question with CSS3 and HTML5 I was thinking that you don't mind using a modern solution.

**The classic solution (table layout)**

This was my original answer. It still works fine and is the solution with the widest support. Table-layout will [impact your rendering performance](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/#tables) so I would suggest that you use one of the more modern solutions.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/)

---

**Tested in:**

- FF3.5+
- FF4+
- Safari 5+
- Chrome 11+
- IE9+

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="cn"><div class="inner">your content</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cn {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
}
```

---

**Modern solution (transform)**

Since transforms are [fairly well supported now](http://caniuse.com/#search=2d%20transforms) there is an easier way to do it.

**CSS**

```
.cn {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0tc6ycvo/1/)

---

**♥ my favourite modern solution (flexbox)**

I started to use flexbox more and more [its also well supported now](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) Its by far the easiest way.

**CSS**

```
.cn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/meodai/pen/PqRebp?editors=110)

More examples & possibilities:
[Compare all the methods on one pages](http://codepen.io/meodai/pen/XbEqZw?editors=110)

Comment: +1 Would the OP need to wrap any text inside another container if centered text was not desired?

Comment: you can reset it for the inner div: http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/2/

Comment: Looks good to me. Nice solution.

Comment: +1 - but reader should be aware that meo only gets away with this answer because the post is tagged as html5 and css3

Comment: There are some complicated workarounds for the annoying IE's to but they need some additional markup :( http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: Thanks. :) It worked.I reset the text allign of inner div as per your second link and thats what I wanted.

Comment: Whilst this does work it serves as a clean example of why CSS is just so greatly flawed. Something as simple as this should not need cludges and work arounds.

Comment: How important is it to include `display: table;` in the parent element?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/FpPrn/ for a more cmplete answer on the subject! I would also mention, that display:table-cell goes a long way, and to make the answer more complete, it would be ok to wrap the cn div inside another one, whose display is set to table!

Comment: Yet I cannot set position: absolute to the element with display: table-cell right?

Comment: @aokaddaoc table-cell and `position:absolute` never play nice, just try an other method ;)

Comment: The solution is wrap just another div outside the div{ display: table-cell; }

Comment: You seem to be missing "display:flex" for the container in the flexbox example.

Comment: @CpnCrunch I don't ;) Check the examples: http://codepen.io/meodai/pen/XbEqZw?editors=010 its the 4th

Comment: Yes, your example is correct. I was talking about the code in your answer (here). You seem to have "position:flex", which doesn't appear to be a valid css attribute.

Comment: @CpnCrunch my bad, I changed it to display: flex.

Comment: @AndrewS Or a great example to show that most designers still design like print designers...

Comment: This answer ended my frustration after 3 hours of fiddling and trying to get to show that div vertically aligned. That flex example worked perfectly, and since the customer uses IE11/Chrome, I can use it without a problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: One problem, it seems the cn class height needs to be set with absolutely pixels, it doesn't work with height:100%; Oh. just found out when set cn position: absolutely. That works. Thanks!

Comment: I spend about 5 hours to center a div(granted tricky), there are many solutions on the net that do not work (even on stackoverflow). This one works like a charm even if the division centered is nested 15 times in parent divs! Thanks @meo!

Comment: This doesn't work with IE11 if I set min-height... https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/101487/

Comment: Flexbox worked well, thank you. I also added `height: inherit`

Comment: @meo, I think your answer would benefit from the following edit: invert the position of the Flexbox and Table sections. Flexbox rocks!

Comment: Love the flex solution! Only one that really worked in my case (dimensions of cn and inner both in percentages)

Comment: I know that we need to use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to really center the div, but why `top:50%` and `left:50%` alone doesn't work? can someone explain this more?

Comment: Also `display: grid;` with `place-items: center;` is quite handy for centering:).

Answer (score 130):

Another way of achieving this horizontal and vertical centering is:

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

([Reference](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/))

Comment: +1, but it curiously depends on the order of positions. Starting `bottom: 0; left: 0;` gets the inner div stuck on the bottom of the parent (Chrome 33, anyways).

Comment: define 0 in the orientation that you want your div to get aligned
in my case, in a search form fiel it was
`.search-header{
 margin:auto;
 top:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 right:0px; 
}`

no 'left' asigned to continue the order and position of the previous <div>

Comment: And no need to precise that the parent div must be positioned

Comment: I would say this was the superior solution, but *only* when your inner element’s height can be specified in advance. This makes it unsuitable for vertically centring flowed text, for example.

Comment: Didn't work for left, always aligned to the left (OS/X Chrome 66.0.3359.117)

Comment: this horizontally centered the inner div not vertically.

Answer (score 52):

### Another way is using Transform Translate

Outer Div must set its `position` to `relative` or `fixed`, and the Inner Div must set its `position` to `absolute`, `top` and `left` to `50%` and apply a `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.

```css
div.cn {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}

div.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   
    background: red;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="cn">
    <div class="inner">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Tested in:

- **Opera 24.0** (minimum 12.1)
- **Safari 5.1.7** (minimum 4 with -webkit- prefix)
- **Firefox 31.0** (minimum 3.6 with -moz- prefix, from 16 without prefix)
- **Chrome 36** (minimum 11 with -webkit- prefix, from 36 without prefix)
- **IE 11, 10** (minimum 9 with -ms- prefix, from 10  without prefix)
- [**More browsers, Can I Use?**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: The best part of this code is it works perfect with full-width outer div. Great Job!

Comment: I know that we need to use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to really center the div, but why `top:50%` and `left:50%` alone doesn't work? can someone explain this more?

Comment: @KevinChandra, I think `top` and `left` refers to the container dimensions and the `translate` refers to the content size. hope that helps!

Answer (score 51):

[Vertical Align Anything with just 3 lines of CSS](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

HTML

```
<div class="parent-of-element">

    <div class="element">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Simplest

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

CSS

```
.parent-of-element {
   position: relative;
   height: 500px;
   /* or height: 73.61% */
   /* or height: 35vh */
   /* or height: ANY HEIGHT */
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;

  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

According to [shouldiprefix](http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms) this are the only prefixes you need

You can also use % as the value for the 'height' property of .parent-of-element, as long as parent of element has height or some content that expands its vertical size.

Comment: can't tell you why, but in my case this worked perfectly when i used (50%) instead of (-50%) on translateY...

Comment: I love this solution for its elegance. The only problem is that if the user squashes their browser to 100px high (for example), I lose the top of the centered <div>, which is problematic for me because I want my header there for aesthetic/design reasons. To be perfectly honest, though: I like this solution so much, I'm not even sure I care!

Comment: KjetilNordin, depending on your layout it sometimes work when you use 50% instead of -50%. But as long as the container of the centered element has a height, the -50% will work flawlessly.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of tying myself in a knot with hard-to-write and hard-to-maintain CSS (that also needs careful cross-browser validation!) I find it far better to give up on CSS and use instead wonderfully simple HTML 1.0:

```
<table id="outerDiv" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" id="innerDiv">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This accomplishes everything the original poster wanted, and is robust and maintainable.

Comment: Most people do not consider this to be a good practice, and I agree. Markup elemets like "table" should not be used for layout. Use table if you are actually displaying a tabular data.

Comment: If you value style over maintainable code, then your concern is valid.      Other people may weigh those two factors differently, and they should see all options.

Comment: i think this solution is great absolutely cross-browser

Comment: As @Milan says, this solution is not perfect. But neither is any other.

Comment: Despite the CSS nazis and their hatred for tables, I find this solution far better than piling up cryptic CSS directives which rely on a table-cell format anyway. CSS in its current state simply can't handle this properly.

Comment: One vote for implying that css is piling up a bunch of workarounds (at least in terminology) to achieve this simple thing. For a developer this definitely a more manageable solution, which I would hope it will not be needed in the future.

Comment: I prefer the simplicity and maintainability of this solution.

Comment: The google-mandated need to adhere to RWD standards is going to kill tables. Otherwise, I agree: tables worked beautifully in their heyday, and <div>s have always been a pain in the a** to get to function as cleanly and well.

Comment: I would have to break away from the rest of the commentators here and say that I do not agree that this is more manageable nor understandable, yet is simpler. When discussing ideas of manageability and understanding, I can only assume that we are thinking of keeping our "reason" recognizable by later developers. When using table elements specifically for vertical alignment, the mechanics are unarguably simple, yet your reason is in no way clear and the later developer may be left wondering what is being done. CSS classes are, in a sense, much more definitive despite their complexity.

Comment: @WebWanderer: (1) `valign-"middle"` would seem to be pretty clear.  (2) If lack of clarity is a problem, it is easy to add a comment.  (3) In looking at the top-voted answer, I can say without hesitation that its meaning is opaque to my eye. (4) If two pieces of code or markup accomplish the same thing, then they are, by definition, equally definitive.  I think the word you're looking for is "perspicacity" and that is in the eye of the beholder. i.e. is subjective.

Comment: I personally prefer the clean HTML markup of DIVs to Tables, especially because if I plan on re-skinning a page, I don't necessarily have to change the HTML. I can just change the CSS, whereas I feel more limited to each row in a table.

Answer (score 14):

*You can do it by simply adding css style mentioned below. This is supported by most of the browsers. You can check [here](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) for the browser support. All the best. For any query please comment*

```css
#outerDiv {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position:relative;
        background:grey;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
    }

#innerDiv {
        background:cyan;
        width: 284px;
        height: 290px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv">
        Inner Div
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer the trick of using a hidden pseudo element to span the full height of the outer container, and vertically aligning it with the other content.
Chris Coyier has a nice article on the technique. http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/
The huge advantage of this is scalability. You don't have to know the height of the content or worry about it growing/shrinking. This solution scales :).

Here's a fiddle with all the CSS you'll need and a working example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/m5sLze0d/

```
.center:before {
    content: ""; /* Adding Extra Space Above Element */
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -0.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.center_element {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space:normal;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: 6 years later, this is the best solution!

Answer (score 5):

If you still didn't understand after reading the marvellous answers given above.

Here are two simple examples of how you can achieve it.

> [Using display: table-cell](https://jsfiddle.net/shivamsupr/103zgb52/3/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #cd0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    Center align a div using "<strong>display: table-cell</strong>"
  </div>
</div>
```

> [Using flex-box (display: flex)](https://jsfiddle.net/shivamsupr/71meeLca/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.container {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #cd0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        Centering a div using "<strong>display: flex</strong>"
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Check the browser compatibility of display: table-cell and flex before using the above mentioned implementations.

Answer (score 4):

#### Vertically centering div items inside another div

Just set the container to `display:table` and then the inner items to `display:table-cell`. Set a `height` on the container, and then set `vertical-align:middle` on the inner items. This has broad compatibility back as far as the days of IE9.

Just note that the vertical alignment will depend on the height of the parent container.

```css
.cn
{
display:table;
height:80px;
background-color:#555;
}

.inner
{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
color:#FFF;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cn">
  <div class="inner">Item 1</div>
  <div class="inner">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

When your `height` is not set (auto); you can give inner div some padding (top and bottom) to make it vertically center:

```
<div>
    <div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px">
    <!--content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Vertically centering a div inside another div

```css
#outerDiv{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
  
  background-color: lightgrey;  
}

#innerDiv{
  width: 284px;
  height: 290px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
  <div id="innerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**I have been using the following solution since over a year, it works with IE 7 and 8 as well.**

```
<style>
.outer {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.outer .emptyDiv {
    height: 100%;
    background: orange;
    visibility: collapse;
}

.outer .inner {
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
}

.verticalCenter {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="emptyDiv verticalCenter"></div>
    <div class="inner verticalCenter">
        <p>Line 1</p>
        <p>Line 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Width and hight of the outer div can be defined.

**Here the code:**

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; // Any height is allowed, also in %.
  background: gray;
}

.outer > div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Put here your text or div content!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle Link <  http://jsfiddle.net/dGHFV/2515/>

**Try this**

```
   #outerDiv{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid red;
    }

    #innerDiv{
        width: 284px;
        height: 290px;
        position:absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left:0px;
        right:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for innerdiv which do not specify it's height value,there is no pure css solution to make it vertically centered.a javascript solution could be get the innerdiv's offsetHeight,then calculate the style.marginTop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple javascript (jQuery) block.

**CSS**:

```
#outerDiv{
    height:100%;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#innerDiv").css('top', ($(window).height() - $("#content").height()) / 2);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to align inner element like this:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
display: table;
```

and of course:

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: it's vertically not horizontally

Answer (score 1):

You can center the div vertically and horizontally in CSS using flex;

```
#outerDiv{
width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    }

#innerDiv{
    width: 284px;
    height: 290px;
    border:1px solid #eee;

}
```

And the second one is as following;

```
    #outerDiv{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid #000;
        }

        #innerDiv{
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
        position:absolute; 
        left:0;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid #000;
        border-radius:4px;
    }
```

And the resulting HTML:

```
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <div id="innerDiv"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvA9m.png)   **100% it works**

```
.div1{
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.div2{
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

    <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
      sdfd
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Mangesh1556/btn1mozd/4/

Comment: this works great

Answer (score 1):

**This will work way back to IE6!**

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is required on IE6 too!
[ will force IE6 default strict mode as well ].

( of course, the box coloring is for demo purposes only )

```css
#outer{
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        margin: auto; 
        text-align: center;
    }
    #inner{
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: .3em;
    }
    #center{
        height: 100%; width:0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    div {background: rgba(0,110,255,.7)}
```

```html
<DIV id=outer>
<div id=center>
</div><!--Don't break this line!--><div id=inner>
The inner DIV
</div>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show another cross-browser way which can solve this question using CSS3 `calc()`.

We can use the `calc()` function to control the `margin-top` property of the child div when it's positioned absolute relative to the parent div.

The main advantage using `calc()` is that the parent element height can be changed at anytime and the child div will always be aligned to the middle.

The `margin-top` calculation is made dynamically (by css and not by a script and it's a very big **advantage**).

Check out this [LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=c7ff7cd5-d8f6-4ec5-919c-7df62d1cc230)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #parent{
        background-color:blue;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position:relative;
      }
      #child{
        background-color:red;
        width: 284px;
        height: 250px;
        position:absolute;
        /* the middle of the parent(50%) minus half of the child (125px) will always             
           center vertically the child inside the parent */
        margin-top: -moz-calc(50% - 125px);
        /* WebKit */
        margin-top: -webkit-calc(50% - 125px);
        /* Opera */
        margin-top: -o-calc(50% - 125px);
        /* Standard */
        margin-top: calc(50% - 125px);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="child">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

text align-center on parent element, display inline-block on child element. This will center all most anything. I believe its call a "block float".

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner"> some content </div>
</div><!-- end outer -->

<style>
div.outer{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
div.inner{
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: left
}
</style>
```

This is also a good alternative for float's, good luck!

Comment: your answer is related to horizontal centering; the question is about centering vertically

Answer (score 0):

To center align both vertically and horizontally:

```
#parentDiv{
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}

#child {
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I know that question was created year ago...
Anyway thanks CSS3 you can easily vertically aligns div in div (example there http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/98/)

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
<div>
Go to Hell!
</div>
</div>

div
{
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in Safari.

Comment: This will only work in browsers using the Mozilla framework (such as Firefox). It's bad practice to provide/use code that isn't cross-browser friendly.