# Centering div using percentage margins

Tags: css, html

I'm centering a div inside another div using percentage margins. I do this because the parent div is going to change sizes based on browser size.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/bNXww/) for a demo.

My CSS:

```
#test-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.white-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    left: 50%; margin-left: -25%;
    top: 50%; margin-top: -25%;
}
```

This works fine in Safari, but in Chrome the child `div` is appearing higher than it should.

Perhaps there's a better way to achieve such a thing, that works on all browsers and doesn't rely on pixel margins? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `all browsers` include the latest browser versions only or something like IE7 too?

Comment: For horizontal alignment I'd recomment using something like [`margin: 0 auto;`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/419956).

Comment: Vertical alignment however [is slightly trickier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6490252/419956).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my favorite way to accomplish this (works in all modern browsers and IE8+).

```
<style>
/* Can be any width and height */
.block {
  height:500px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can be any width or height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
</style>

<div class="block"><div class="centered">Centered Content</div></div>
```

And here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/tRwUw/) that mimics your example.

Comment: nice, very nice! Although, the `.block` div is 300px inside the 500px parent, I was hoping the child div would be a percentage of it's parent, if at all possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the attribute **margin**. So your CSS of **white-wrap** should be:

```
.white-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#test-wrap {
   display: table-cell;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.white-wrap {
     display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, centering text horizontally inside the `.white-wrap` might be a bit tricky though: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/bNXww/23/ ?

Comment: sorry I meant to say 'vertically', centering the text inside `.white-wrap` vertically may be quite tricky

Answer (score 0):

You should set those properties too :

```
* {
  box-sizing:                 border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:            border-box; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-box-sizing:         border-box; /* Safari */
}
```

Once you defined a size for a DIV or anything else, the margin, padding and everything will be in the sizing and won't increase the size.