# Two inline-block elements, each 50% wide, do not fit side by side in a single row

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Width issue</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#left {
    width: 50%;
    background: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    background: orange;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5EcPK/

The above code is trying to place the #left div and the #right div, side by side, in a single row. But as you can see in the above JSFiddle URL, this is not the case.

I am able to resolve the issue reducing the width of one of the divs to 49%. See http://jsfiddle.net/mUKSC/ . But this is not an ideal solution because a small gap appears between the two divs.

Another way I am able to solve the problem is by floating both the divs. See http://jsfiddle.net/VptQm/ . This works fine.

But my original question remains. Why when both the divs are kept as inline-block elements, they do not fit side by side?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

**Update**: as it's 2021, use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) or even better - [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead of `inline-block`.

---

When using `inline-block` elements, there will always be an `whitespace` **issue between those elements** (that space is about 4px wide).

So, your two `divs`, which both have 50% width, plus that `whitespace`(~ 4px) is more than 100% in width, and so it breaks. Example of your problem:

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default body margin */
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.left{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">foo</div>
<div class="right">bar</div>
```

---

There is a few ways to fix that:

**1. No space between those elements**

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default body margin */
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.left{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">foo</div><div class="right">bar</div>
```

**2. Using HTML comments**

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default body margin */
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.left{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">foo</div><!--
--><div class="right">bar</div>
```

**3. Set the parents `font-size` to `0`, and then adding some value to `inline-block` elements**

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default body margin */
}

.parent{
  font-size: 0;  /* parent value */
}

.parent > div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px; /* some value */
}

.left{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">foo</div>
  <div class="right">bar</div>
</div>
```

**4. Using a negative margin between them ([not preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro/18262352#comment30510977_18262337))**

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default body margin */
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: -4px; /* negative margin */
}

.left{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">foo</div>
<div class="right">bar</div>
```

**5. Dropping closing angle**

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default body margin */
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.left{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">foo</div
><div class="right">bar</div>

<hr>

<div class="left">foo</div><div class="right">
bar</div>
```

**6. Skipping [certain](https://developers.whatwg.org/syntax.html#optional-tags) HTML closing tags** (thanks @thirtydot for the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/1763929))

```css
body{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default body margin */
}

ul{
  margin: 0; /* removing the default ul margin */
  padding: 0; /* removing the default ul padding */
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.left{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.right{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="left">foo
  <li class="right">bar
</ul>
```

---

References:

1. [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)
2. [Remove Whitespace Between Inline-Block Elements by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)
3. [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

---

As [@MarcosPérezGude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035890/marcos-p%C3%A9rez-gude) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro/18262352#comment60598187_18262352), the **best** way is to use [`rem`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem), and add some default value to `font-size` on the `html` tag (like in [HTML5Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/css/main.css#L15)). Example:

```
html{
    font-size: 1em;
}

.ib-parent{             /* ib -> inline-block */
    font-size: 0;
}

.ib-child{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

---

Comment: @hoosierEE that's not nosense. The space between elements is fine, it's because inline-block elements will positioning at the text line. If you put a space in a line, there will be a space. So the behaviour is the correct, even if you think that's an issue (as Vucko call it wrong).

Comment: I agree with @MarcosPérezGude, this behaviour is correct. As you can see from my post, there are a few ways to remove that whitespace (I myself use HTML comments to remove the white space). But if you mind that white space, you can always use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [`table/table-row/table-cell`](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero) or use `float`.

Comment: I use inline-blocks perfectly. My normal approach is `parent { font-size:0; } child {font-size: 1rem;  }`. With rems now is easiest

Comment: it's a little annoying that tabs are still parsed as spaces. i've never seen that dropping the closing tag fix before, does that have any instability or side-effects?

Comment: Also make sure `border` is off. This can add space if you're floating the divs.

Comment: @evolross check about [box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Answer (score 28):

good answer in css3 is:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in parent node, and :

```
white-space: normal;
vertical-align: top;
```

in div (or other) at 50%

exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/YpTMh/19/

EDIT:

there is another way with :

```
font-size: 0;
```

for parent node and override it in child node

EDIT 2021 : personaly, I recommand use flexbox now : https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 7):

It's because the whitespace between your two divs is being interpreted as a space. If you put your `<div>` tags in line as shown below the [problem is corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/5EcPK/5/):

```
<div id="left"></div><div id="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Either make them block instead of inline-block. This will render divs ignoring spaces between them.

```
display:block;
```

or remove space between tags

```
<div id='left'></div><div id='right'></div>
```

or add

```
margin: -1en;
```

to one of the divs in order to mitigate space taken by single space rendered.

Answer (score 4):

Because there is a space between the elements. If you remove all whitespace, [they will fit](http://jsfiddle.net/QgpNY/).

```
<div id="left">Left</div><div id="right">Right</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#left {
    width: 50%;
    background: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    background: orange;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by adding the css display:inline to the div that holds the inline elements.

While removing the white space using margin with a negative value it becomes necessary to add it to this particular element. As adding it to a class will affect places where this class has been used.

So it would be safer to use display:inline;

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox example - this would be used for the parent class holding the two side by side elements.

```
.parentclass {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

Taken from [Vertically centering a div inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div/6490283#6490283)

Answer (score 0):

add **float: left;** to both div tags.

```css
div {
  float: left;
}
```