# 3 Inline Div, how to horizontally stretch the middle one

Tags: html, inline

Trying to build a reponsive header for my website.

I have 3 inline div (inside a parent div), first & last one have fixed width, & I want the middle one to horizontally fill the empty space.  What is the best method to do that in CSS ?  Should I use display: table ?  I Hate table & I know they are not supposed to be used to create the layout of a website.

Should look like that : <-LEFTDIV-> <-----MIDDLEDIV---this one stretch to fill empty space> <-RIGHTDIV->

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: You can use `calc`. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645861/html-layout-that-has-flexible-left-pane-and-a-fixed-right-left-cant-wrap-must/18667921#18667921) of a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but calc doesnt seem to be well supported in older browser...

Comment: That's true. If you need older browser support, use JavaScript.