# Drawing rectangles with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a use case whereby I want to draw rectangles in CSS. I need them to look like this:

[image: Desired block layout]

I've managed to get the smaller and taller boxes drawn but can't work out how to draw those that drop below the line. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WtuyL/3/)

**Heres' my HTML:**

```
<div class="word">
    <p class="letter taller"></p>
    <p class="letter"></p>
    <p class="letter"></p>
    <p class="letter hanging"></p>
    <p class="letter"></p>
    <p class="letter taller"></p>
    <p class="letter"></p>
</div>
```

**Here's my CSS so far:**

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.letter {
    padding 1.618em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;

}
.taller {
    height: 4em;
}

.hanging {
 /* not sure what to implement here */
}
```

Comment: [Will this suit](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/WtuyL/5/)?

Comment: Use a negative `margin-bottom` as Vucko suggested

Comment: Yes +1. it didn't even occur to me to move the margin-bottom down using a negative value.

Comment: @Luke that's why we're here - to help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using margins may affect other elements, especially if you plan on including other content on your page. ([See this](http://jsfiddle.net/WtuyL/8/)) I'd recommend using `position: relative` combined with `top: 2em`. What that does is it pushes the element down `2em`, *relative* to the original position of the element.

```
.hanging {
  height: 4em; 
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WtuyL/6/

(On an unrelated note... [here's a little bonus](http://jsfiddle.net/WtuyL/7/) if you want to fully imitate the image and remove whitespace. You'll net to set a manual size to all `<p>` elements though.)

Comment: I understand how the answers using `margin-bottom`work. I'll have to look up what top does to work this one out. Thanks.

Comment: While a negative `margin-bottom` works, it's kind of hackish trick; I'd definitely recommend this solution instead.

Comment: Added a little explanation! Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for adding the explanation.  I'd love to see more people explaining the _why_ as well as the _how_.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use a negative `margin-bottom` to achieve this (you don't need to use `positioning`):

**CSS**:

```
.hanging {
    margin-bottom: -16px;
    height:4em;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/WtuyL/5/)

**Note**: also comment the whitespace between `display:inline-block` elements to remove it.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro/18262352#18262352) - see this to see more *hacks* how to remove the *whitespace* between `display:inline-block` elements.

Comment: +1 for getting the fiddle up so quickly and for the whitespace hack but I think I'm going to go with the `top: 2em;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.hanging {
    height:4em;
    margin-bottom:-1em;
}
```