# How to make two divs side by side using inline-block?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the divs side by side and one of the div ('contentwrapper') be responsive to the browser resizing.

HMTL

```
<div id="maincontainer">
<div id="leftcolumn">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="contentwrapper">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#maincontainer {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#leftcolumn {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#contentwrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JSFIDDLE **http://jsfiddle.net/A5HM7/**

Comment: @BuddhistBeast same line as the browser

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<style>
  #maincontainer {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #leftcolumn {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
  }

  #contentwrapper {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I think this will be the quickest fix for you. You already have a great html structure but I am going to narrow it down more for you. Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5HM7/4/).

With your code:

```
#maincontainer {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have made a minor adjustment like so:

```
#maincontainer {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;//added this
}
```

and then I also restructured two other things like so:

```
#leftcolumn {
    float:left;//added this
    width: 100px;
    height:100%;
    background: blue;
}
#contentwrapper {
    float:right;//added this
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now in this JsFiddle, I have appropriately created a specific width, so you can always change that. Please keep in mind that if you use 100% as a width, and try to stick something else in that same line, it will automatically create two lines such like so:

```
#leftcolumn {
    display:inline-block;<-- changed this above.
    width: 100px;<----This won't work with the below
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#contentwrapper {
    display:inline-block;<---- changed this above.
    width:100%;<---- This won't work with the above
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

But if you restructure that to be more like this:

```
#leftcolumn {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 10%;<---This will work with the below
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#contentwrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    width:90%;<---This will work with the above.
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

A few things to note, I did add in a height with the JsFiddle so that I could see the actual dimensions and I also added in width for the exact reason. Something to note that can really help out with implementations and the basic "why does this work" is [this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/).

Comment below if something doesn't work for you :)

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to get 2 div's beside each other without using float's or absolute positioning.
I'm using the calc function which is supported in IE9 and above.
[MDN calc specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
And don't forget the space blocker [Stackoverflow: 50% wont fit because hidden space between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro)

```
<!-- HMTL -->
<div id="maincontainer">
<div id="leftcolumn">&nbsp;</div><!-- space blocker
--><div id="contentwrapper">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#maincontainer {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#leftcolumn {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

#contentwrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple possibilities, but the easiest is using flexbox. See the documentation of the flexible box layout module for more info. Note that it is still a candidate recommendation, so some browsers could have problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#maincontainer {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#leftcolumn {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 340px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#contentwrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 340px;  // see how this is equal to the width of #left-column
    position: absolute; // might want to try with this or position relative
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%; // might want to try with or without this line
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```