# Two 50% width divs don't fit in parent

Tags: html, css

Sorry if it is a duplicate of something, I have searched honestly, but I still have the problem which is shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tfvdzzee/1/

The code here:

html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrap
{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#one, #two
{
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
}
#two
{
    float: right;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: You only floated one of them.
Float #one left and it should work

Comment: Or `display: inline-block;` can work too (in #one, #two).

Comment: @Sifu, would only work if you commented out the white space between them

Comment: @Sifu Since the width is 50% display:inline-block will push the 2nd block down.

Comment: @ezaz ? http://jsfiddle.net/rhn8u1pz/

Comment: @TobyOsborne idk why, but float:left to #one crashes parent's border in my fiddle.

Comment: @VIRUS because you don't have `overflow: hidden;`. See SW4's answer.

Comment: Hey I added an answer which fixed the float issue; the cause is that floating an element kind of takes it out of flow from the container which is why using clear:both after the floats is required.

Check my answer below which I also included the display:inline-block method as well just in case you want to experiment.

Comment: It's insane that the whitespace between the dwo divs causes `inline-block`s to be pushed down... it's clearly not displayed anywhere and yea.. annoying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two inline-block elements, each 50% wide, do not fit side by side in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `display: inline-block;` is the best answer, as it prevents bugs of overlapping and overflowing, while also keeping its parent definitions.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rhn8u1pz/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">1</div><!--
 --><div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap
{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#one, #two
{
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    /* If worried about IE7 and IE6, add the two next lines */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}

#two
{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... It works! I wonder, I have made 2 pages like this but `display: inline-block` didn't help, but now. I am confused. But thank you.

Comment: @VIRUS It's probably because you didn't comment out the whitespace between the two divs.

Comment: @TylerH I would never understand this if u didn't say. I am done :D

Answer (score 4):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/tfvdzzee/4/)

You need to **both** `float:left` the `#one` element as well as set `overflow:hidden` to the parent to ensure it wraps the children correctly.

Change your CSS to:

```
#wrap
{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden; /* <---ensure the parent wraps the children */

}

#one, #two
{
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
    float:left; /* <---ensure the children display inline */
}

#two
{
    float: right;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following style in your CSS.

```
 #one{float:left}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/tfvdzzee/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Css property for **#two** and add this

```
#one, #two
{
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @Sifu - no it wouldn't... unless they had absolute poitioning

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: left` and you don't need `float: right` for `#two`.

```
#one, #two
{
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}

#two
{
    background: red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmnxdxf2/) example.

Comment: This moves them outside of the border that is applied to #wrap

Answer (score 1):

You will need to float both your divs. After the float, clear the float using the clearfix class.

CSS:

```
#one, #two{ float:left; }

.clearfix:after {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   font-size: 0;
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/tfvdzzee/6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
#wrap
{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#wrap:after{
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
}

#one, #two
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    background: green;
}

#two
{
    background: red;
}
```

Try this and use clearfix on the `:after` pseudo element of your `#wrap` div.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/tfvdzzee/3/)

Comment: Why so complicated, while you can just use inline-blocks?

Answer (score -2):

To Expand on the comment by sifu and answer the question in a choice of ways

**The first method (Using float's)**

```
#wrap
{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#one,#two
{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfvdzzee/7/

**Display Inline-block method**

```
#wrap
{
   max-width: 400px;
   margin: auto;
   border: 2px solid black;
   font-size:0px;
}
#one,#two
{
   width:50%;
   display:inline-block;
   font-size:16px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfvdzzee/8/

Both methods can be used however if you are still developing for IE7 (not sure why you would) then method 2 wont work.

Comment: Please don't copy other peoples' answers and post them as your own, even if to consolidate them into one answer. New answers should add new ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Method 2 works with the simple css hack :  `{display:inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1;}`

Comment: Sifu - Thanks I didn't know that myself appreciate it. - sorry if you feel I copied your answer.

@TylerH - If you look at our answers they are not completely the same; we get around the white space issue differently. I mentioned  Sifu's answer as they have similarities and I noticed that he posted a comment on the question that seemed to be getting burned out a little for a perfectly good answer. I apologies