# Arrange two divs inline in footer

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/

I want to fix these two div sites so as to be in line as in the picture below

http://i58.tinypic.com/2n8ucuu.jpg

This is the HTML code:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">


            <div class="social-list">

                   <ul>
                      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri1.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
                      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri2.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
                      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri3.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
                      <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri4.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>
                       <li><img src="http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/eventos/images/gri5.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30"></li>

                   </ul>

            </div>


    <div class="site-info">


        <?php printf( __( ' © 2015 %1$s %2$s.', 'eventos' ), 'EVENTOS.', 'Toate drepturile rezervate' ); ?>


    </div><!-- .site-info -->
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

I tried to put display: inline-block div at the two sites, but unfortunately does not work ... and do not understand why

Can you please help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put float:left on both of your div's and get rid of the inline-block

Comment: Floats should be considered a last resort. They cause as many problems as they solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
footer#colophon > div {
    display: inline-block; /* allow block-level elements to reside on the same line */
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* make borders and padding part of dimensions */
    font-size: 0; /* eliminate remaining whitespace between */
}
```

[More on dealing with the whitespace niggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro)