# Cannot get widths to work with grid

Tags: html, sass

I am working on playing around with a mini grid and even though my column widths equal up to 100% the third column is wrapping. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/d866tc0q/

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">Here 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Here 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Here 3</div>
</div>
```

SASS (See JS fiddle for full SASS)

```
$width = 100%;
$max-col = 12;

.row {
    width: $width;
}

.col-md-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: percentage((2 / 12));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So if I add float left to the columns then it works but I thought inline block would save me from having to put the floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with whitespaces, easiest solution is to write your html inline:

```
<div class="row"><div class="bor col-md-7">Here 1</div><div class="bor col-md-3">Here 2</div><div class="bor col-md-2">Here 3</div></div>
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d866tc0q/8/).

Or you can change `font-size` of parent to `0`, and give its children some font-size value ie. `font-size: 1em`

Last solution could be negative margins on children (as other answer suggested).

Also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro) for more info.

Comment: I like the font size idea the best

Answer (score 0):

Just take a couple pixels off -

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-md-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: percentage((2 / 12));
    margin: -2px;
}

.col-md-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: percentage((3 / 12));
    margin: -2px;
}

.col-md-7 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: percentage((7 / 12));
    margin: -2px;
}
```

Comment: DRY `%sameStuff {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -2px;
}
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
  .col-md-#{$i} { 
    width: percentage(($i / 12));
    @extend %sameStuff;
  }
}`  ;)