# Display two divs next to each other where each has a width of 50%

Tags: html, css

My HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">The two divs are</div>
    <div id="div2">next to each other.</div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:120px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:160px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrios_87/d5Z6V/11/)

So, when as you can see the width of each div is 49%, that's the only way I'm getting it to work. If you set the width of each to 50%, the divs aren't displayed next to each other anymore... Why is that?

Comment: It is because you have a border of 1 px on each side. The box-model then makes the div 50% wide + 2px on each side, the 2px being your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two inline-block elements, each 50% wide, do not fit side by side in a single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro)

Comment: This question has been answered so many times here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of two things

1. Border size so you need to change `box-sizing` to `border-box`
2. White space on `inline-block` elements

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">The two divs are</div><div id="div2">next to each other.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: IMPORTANT: It is necessary that the two divs are written in one line! I would recommend an edit, but queue is full.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the line break between the `<div>` tags and `box-sizing:border-box;`
    
      The two divs arenext to each other.

Another approach would be to use float

```
    #wrapper {
        border: 1px solid blue;box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    #div1 {
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        height:120px;
        background:green;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #909090;
    }
    #div2 {
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        height:160px;
        background:green;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #909090;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use Flex.

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
}
#div1 {
    width:50%;
    height:120px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#div2 {
    width:50%;
    height:160px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have added a border of `1px` to `wrapper`. Your border with take 2px of total width of your page.

If you wanna keep the border and still keep the width of each div as 50%, you can refer to @NenadVracar 's answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `calc()` and calculate the width to be `50% - 2px`. I'm just listing that as an option @Nenad Vracar has the right answer