# Placing two p elements next to each other with a width of 50%

Tags: html, css

I have this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/105nfcze/55/

```css
#footer-a {
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#footer-b {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapc">
  <p id="footer-a"> Footer </p>
  <p id="footer-b">
    <a href="#">test 1</a>
    <a href="#">test 12</a>
    <a href="#">test 13</a> </p>

</div>
```

I have also followed this link: [Display two divs next to each other where each has a width of 50%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600614/display-two-divs-next-to-each-other-where-each-has-a-width-of-50)

I have also tried floating, as what is said in this link :
[How to place two divs next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other?rq=1)

But still I do not get the two p's places next to each other. I tried several things and looked up several QA's. Hope someone can advise and also explain why this happens..

Comment: if inline-block is involved, mind the white-space in the HTML code ...

Comment: question - why not use `<div>`?

Comment: good question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex on the parent:

```css
.content-wrapc {
  /* add this */
  display: flex;
}

#footer-a {
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
}

#footer-b {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapc">
  <p id="footer-a"> Footer </p>
  <p id="footer-b">
    <a href="#">test 1</a>
    <a href="#">test 12</a>
    <a href="#">test 13</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem with your original code is that you use inline block - this adds a space if there is any space between your elements (think of words in a sentence, if there is space between them, a space is added) which is why the two 50% elements can't sit next to each other

Comment: This works like a charm, mind if you can also give a little explanation??

Comment: Flexbox aligns all child items in a row by default - therefore it will align the two paragraphs in a row and as they have a width of 50% each, they will take up the full width of the row.  [Here is a good codepen explaining flexbox properties](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv)

Comment: @YdB display: table/table-cell , flex, grid or float will not create that white space bothering you with inline-block . Flex is the **nowdays** method to use most of the time ;)