# Margins appearing around padded links

Tags: html, css

I'm making a set of navigation links. Whenever their :hover stylings are activated it becomes obvious that there is a small (maybe 2px?) margin all around the link. I've tried using `margin:0;` on the `a` styles to remove it, with no success. I've also tried setting `margin:0;` on the parent `div`, but again, no luck.

I've included the code in a snippet below to illustrate the problem. Does anyone know what is causing this and, in turn, how to fix it?

Thank you!

```css
/* Animations */
div#top > div#nav-container a:hover {
  color:#f7902b;
  background-color:#fff;
}

/* Regular CSS */
div#top {
  background-color:#333;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
div#top > div#nav-container {
  text-align:center;
}
div#top > div#nav-container a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;

  padding:10px 20px;

  transition:color 0.25s,background-color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/custom/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top" class="col-md-12">
      <div id="logo-container" style="margin:auto;width:200px;">
        <img src="assets/images/logo-banner.png" style="width:100%;" />
      </div>
      <hr style="margin:10px 0 10px 0;border-color:#444;" />
      <div id="nav-container">
        <a href="#">Breaking</a>
        <a href="#">Politics</a>
        <a href="#">Military</a>
        <a href="#">Economy</a>
        <a href="#">Development</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any margin on Chrome in OS X.

Comment: I don't see any on jsbin.com either.

Comment: clear the css cache of your browser and look again

Comment: [This](https://gyazo.com/fca69b5174d4c96fd278fa6b3dd8e900) is how it looks on my screen (I changed the background colour to red to make it more obvious). I've cleared my cache and it still renders like this.

Comment: It's due to letter spacing between inline elements. You could place all the <a>s on the same line in the HTML or you could float them.

Comment: @powerbuoy, thank you! I can't use `float:left` because obviously it makes all of the links pull left instead of being center like they're supposed to be, and having all of the links on the same line makes the code look messy, but I suppose I'll have to put up with it. Mind putting it as an actual answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two inline-block elements, each 50% wide, do not fit side by side in a single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the spacing between the menu is not `margin` but the width of the inline element which in this case is space.

The possible solution for the problem are: [Working sample is attached for solution #1]

1. *(Using CSS)* setting the `font-size` to `0px` of the container block and setting the `font-size` of the `a` tag to display the content. [see the snippet below]
2. *(Modifying HTML)* commenting between lines to avoid inline space (which is a not a proper solution in my opinion)
3. using float (which you don't want)

snippet for implementing **solution #1**

```
div#top > div#nav-container {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:0px;
}
div#top > div#nav-container a{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

for implementing **solution #2** (Not preffered)

```
<div id="nav-container"><!--
        --><a href="#">Breaking</a><!--
        --><a href="#">Politics</a><!--
        --><a href="#">Military</a><!--
        --><a href="#">Economy</a><!--
        --><a href="#">Development</a><!--
--></div>
```

```css
/* Animations */
div#top > div#nav-container a:hover {
  color:#f7902b;
  background-color:#fff;
}

/* Regular CSS */
div#top {
  background-color:#333;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
div#top > div#nav-container {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:0px;
}
div#top > div#nav-container a{
  font-size:15px;
}
div#top > div#nav-container a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;

  padding:10px 20px;

  transition:color 0.25s,background-color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/custom/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top" class="col-md-12">
      <div id="logo-container" style="margin:auto;width:200px;">
        <img src="assets/images/logo-banner.png" style="width:100%;" />
      </div>
      <hr style="margin:10px 0 10px 0;border-color:#444;" />
      <div id="nav-container">
        <a href="#">Breaking</a>
        <a href="#">Politics</a>
        <a href="#">Military</a>
        <a href="#">Economy</a>
        <a href="#">Development</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not margin it's white space.
links are inline elements and the space you see is just whitespace. you can do two things:

1) have them like this in your html

```
<a href="#"></a><a href="#"></a><a href="#"></a><a href="#"></a>
```

but this is not suggested.

2) use the common ul and li structure for your menu

3) make your `div#top > div#nav-container a {display:inline-block}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but it works.

```
div#nav-container a {
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about the 1px gap around the link when hovering, just adjust your `padding` to fill the space as the following:

```
div#top > div#nav-container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    transition: color 0.25s,background-color 0.5s;
}
```

like the image below
[image]