# How do I center align a div within another div

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I'm trying to center align a div that is located within another div. I want to vertically center the "options" div that is located inside the "plan-container"

Thanks in advance.

```css
.plan-container {
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 62px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}

.options {
    float: left;
    width: 151px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

.plan {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: 23px;
    background-color: purple;
}

.plan:last-child {
    float: right;
}

.plan-featured{
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="plan-container">
  <div class="options">Options</div>
  <div class="plan">Box one</div>
  <div class="plan plan-featured">Box two</div>
  <div class="plan">Box three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` instead of `float`, and than you can use the `vertical-align` property:

```
.plan-container>div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ee1hdvpn/)

However, [beware of the *whitespace* issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro/18262352#18262352).

Answer (score 1):

Vucko's answer is correct. I wanted to add a comment, but since I don't have enough reputation yet, I'll just post it as an answer.

You can use the `vertical-align` property on the inner `div` that needs centering. This property only works on elements that have `display:inline-block` or `display:table`. Refer to the actual spec [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Repeating Vucko's answer:

```
.options {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it-

```
.plan-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* optional. only if you want the items to wrap */
    justify-content: center; /* for horizontal alignment */
    align-items: center; /* for vertical alignment */
}
```

Comment: Will this align everything inside .plan-container ?

Comment: remove margin-top, and other div width & height, with using this css.