# CSS: Center a child div within a parent div

Tags: css, wordpress

Does any one have any suggestions on how I can center content within 'div.footer-widgets .widget.widget_text' the child div is 'div.widget-wrap'. Here is an image link showing you the area within my browser on a local host: http://postimg.org/image/pr7x4cyk9/

```
div.footer-widgets .widget.widget_text {
height: 250px;
}

.widget.widget_text input#subbutton {
width:200px;
}
```

Please let me know if I should provide any further information, thank you.

Comment: I did notice this, I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: vertically center: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div and half a dozen more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.widget.widget_text input#subbutton {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    position:static;
}
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately, I believe this class targets the green button, but even when applying this code to the class it did not center the button. I would like to center the button and the title/heading.

Comment: PS - When I say center, I mean horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a definite height, you can use padding (top & bottom) to automatically center a div's contents, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52tgjyhf/1/).

(renamed divs to make it easier for me, sorry)

```
#inner {
    width: 266px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 15px;
}
```