# How to make this inner div vertically centered? (Using CSS)

Tags: html, css

There are two divs. I want the inner div to be vertically centered, without giving margins, as I want height of inner div to be auto, because its content can change and height can increase.

Here are the two divs:

**Outer div:**

```
    .frontleft{
    width: 602px;
    height: 450px;
    float: left;
    margin: 35px auto;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**Inner div:**

```
.c1{
height: auto;
width: inherit;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

Comment: No, it's not working. I just tried. It centers horizontally only.

Comment: ow. Sorry my bad. how about this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div)

Comment: I've already tried, this one too. It's not working :(

Comment: what browser are you using for testing? i think the attribute float:left is what's messing up the intended effect. can you try removing that? And then try and use the .cn{display: table-cell;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center} for the outer class

Comment: Three valid answers for a broken paradigm: vertical centering elements with CSS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). `display: flex` on parent and `align-self: center` on the child item will center it vertically.

```css
.frontleft {
  width: 602px;
  height: 450px;
  float: left;
  margin: 35px auto;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #2C2955;
  display: flex;
}
.c1 {
  height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  background: #4C5FB1;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="frontleft">
  <div class="c1">Center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! I tried using table it worked. And now I tried your method and it works great even without using table. But please explain how does it work. What means flex and align-self?

Comment: I have updated the link. Flexbox is a modern solution for flexible layout which would be used from/in 2015. Sadly it doesn't support <=IE9. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a table instead? With vertical-align in td tag.

```
      <html>
      <body>
      <table class="frontleft">
      <tr><td>I am a sentence</td></tr>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should position inner element `absolute` and use `transform` property for vertical centering.

```css
.frontleft {
  width: 602px;
  height: 450px;
  float: left;
  margin: 35px auto;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
}
.c1 {
  height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="frontleft">
  <div class="c1">test</div>
</div>
```