# Vertically aligning divs inside another div with 3 lines of code not working

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

This question is a follow-up to [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572034/34806).  I hope it is not considered a duplicate because I want to focus on the particular technique of ["Vertical(ly) align(ing) anything with just 3 lines of CSS"](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/), and because I cannot get the technique to work.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hf31ofj3/ you may only see the issue in HTML 5 browsers because one of the inputs is a color picker, which is a different height than the other input fields, thus causing the vertical mis-alignment.

In any case one thing I've tried to do is change how I am selecting the elements to vertically align as follows, but to no avail

```
#basecfgattrs-row1 #width-input-container
#basecfgattrs-row1 #height-input-container
{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical alignment using `float is often problematical.

Use `display:inline-block` instead...with `vertical-align:middle`.

```css
.input-col3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 32%;
}
#basecfgattrs input {
  width: 44px;
}
#basecfgattrs-row1 {
  position: relative;
}
#basecfgattrs-row1 div {}
```

```html
<div id="basecfgattrs">
  <div id="" basecfgattrs-row1 ">
  <div class="input-col3 " id="width-input-container "> 
   <label>Chart Width</label>
   <input name="width " id="width " />
  </div>
  <div class="input-col3 " id="height-input-container ">
   <label>Chart Height</label>
   <input name="height " id="height " />
  </div>
  <div class="input-col3 " id="dataSource-chart-bgColor-input-container ">
   <label>Background Color</label>
   <input name="dataSource-chart-bgColor " id="dataSource-chart-bgColor " type="color " class="colorpicker " />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Or you could use `flexbox`.**

```css
#basecfgattrs-row1 {
  display: flex;
}
.input-col3 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 32%;
  align-items: center;
}
#basecfgattrs label {
  flex: 1;
}
#basecfgattrs input {
  flex: 0 0 44px;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="basecfgattrs">
  <div id="basecfgattrs-row1">
    <div class="input-col3" id="width-input-container">
      <label>Chart Width</label>
      <input name="width" id="width" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-col3" id="height-input-container">
      <label>Chart Height</label>
      <input name="height" id="height" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-col3" id="dataSource-chart-bgColor-input-container">
      <label>Background Color</label>
      <input name="dataSource-chart-bgColor" id="dataSource-chart-bgColor" type="color" class="colorpicker" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```