# Yet another vertical align CSS issue - two divs top/bottom inside another div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I need the following HTML ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0kLojwx/1/)):

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

To look something like this:

[image]

*Not* like this:

[image]

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div

Comment: Already looked at that. Works for a single `div`, but not two stacked like this.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uh4nxze2/)

Comment: Is there any special reason for setting the height.? if not, remove height and put the padding.

Comment: People are down-voting because the solution is the same for other problems, which is e.g. using `display:table` however the case here is different and deserves it's own question because that's what users search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the display of the parent to table-cell:

```css
.main {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that! Have a ✓ for your time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you change your HTML layout a little ?

```css
.main {
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
}
.inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle
}
.top, .bottom {background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="top">Top</div>
        <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this below.

Comment: This is the better answer, because the parent div should be `display:table` otherwise kinda goofy for child div to use `display:table-cell` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: Close, but [not quite](http://jsfiddle.net/q0kLojwx/2/) (I saw [that article](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) too).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="top">Top</div>
        <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
    line-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper {
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/q0kLojwx/5/