# Vertically aligned text with baselined text group

Tags: css

This is the layout I want to create

[image]

In essence:

1. Word `total` and number `120` should align vertically in the center
2. Words `per month` should align at the bottom w.r.t number 120
3. The word group `120` and `per month` should be right aligned (hence the
   use of `float:right` in css class 'incident-container')

I started with this css style `display:table-cell`. It addressed point 3. However point 1 is not achieved. The vertical alignment does not work.

Demo code can be found here on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kongakong/151eprrk/

It looks like this:

[image]

According to a SO answer ([Vertically centering a div inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div)), I can use `flex` to achieve center alignment.

This is my next attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/kongakong/151eprrk/4/

But it still does not work as I expected:

[image]

Can anyone point out what is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. Just a few fixes needed.

1. No need for `table-cell` on the inner divs. `inline-block` will do.
2. No need for `float` when you are using a table layout.
3. Remove width from the `.frequency`.
4. You are looking for `vertical-align: baseline` instead of `bottom`.

**Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/151eprrk/5/**

**Snippet:**

```css
.incident-banner {
    display: inline-table;
    color: white; background: lightblue;
    margin-top: 20px; width: 100%; height: 75px;
}
.text { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding: 10px 20px; }
.incident-container {
    display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.incident { display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline; font-size: 40px; } 
.frequency {
    display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="incident-banner">
    <div class="text">Total</div>
    <div class="incident-container">
        <div class="incident">120</div>
        <div class="frequency">per month</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your problem -

[**JSbin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/hizagawuzu/edit?html,css,output)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.left span {
  line-height: 40px;
}
.right strong {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.right span {
  font-size: 12px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <span>Total</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <strong>120</strong>
      <span>per month</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/151eprrk/8/)

I just added `line-height` property on `.incident` & `padding-top` property on `.frequency`

```css
.incident-banner {
  display: inline-table;
  color: white;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}
.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.incident-container {
  // display: flex;
  display: table-cell;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.incident {
  display: table-cell;
  // display: inline-block;
  // align-self: center;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 75px;
}
.frequency {
  display: table-cell;
  //align-self: center;
  width: 75px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="incident-banner">
  <div class="text">Total</div>
  <div class="incident-container">
    <div class="incident">120</div>
    <div class="frequency">per month</div>
  </div>
</div>
```