# How to center an element in a column vertically in relation to another column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I center 2 buttons vertically in my view?

For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h4>My List</h4>
            <div style="height:400px; overflow-y:auto">
                <ul>
                    // List of checkboxes
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" id="btnAddField" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" id="btnRemoveField" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h4>Selected Fields</h4>
            // This will contain the list selected from the checkboxes.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the buttons in column 2 to be centered in relation to column 1 (which in this case I made height of 400px.

Comment: Is this bootstrap?

Comment: I am using bootstrap.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered.  Note that bootstrap has little to do with it, as it doesn't provide a means to accomplish this - but there's a few ways to do this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1  or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers?rq=1  or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div?rq=1?

Comment: @cale_b the question the OP is asking is somewhat different from the others, I think it should stand.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new class on `row` that will use `Flexbox` and vertically center items with `align-items: center` when width is `> 992px` which is breakpoint of `md`  [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/591/)

```
@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .flex-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd be careful of using `align-items` vs `margin: auto` for top & bottom. There are a lot of gotchas that manifest themselves in overflow situations.

Comment: That works however it is centering column #3 as well where I only want column #2 to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try `css` Line Height. Hope it will help.

```
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 400px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flexbox, something like this would do what you want (using your existing classes):

```
.row {
    display: flex;

    [class^="col"] {
        float: none;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        margin: auto 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to utilize this snippet, but its doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: My guess is the existing bootstrap css is interfering.