# Center two class with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have the following tag code with two div the bg and the lb:

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.lb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  border: 30px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px #333;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!--bg-->
<div class="bg"></div>
<!--box de imagens-->
<div class="lb">
  <img src="">
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>
```

please see the imagem with the issue and the goal:

[image]

So it is possible to center the two class with CSS3 and achieve the goal of the picture 2? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically centering a div inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div)

Comment: Please change your code in the snippet so your problem becomes visible when running the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

just add negative margin to you `.lb` class or add a transform translate.

```
position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;   
   // SOLUTION ONE
   margin-top: -50%;
   margin-left: -50%;
   // SOLUTION TWO
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   display: none;
   border:30px solid #fff;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px #333;
   background:#fff;                                                     
  }
```

see doc for translate [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)

Comment: Hi kevinniel, the  // SOLUTION TWO    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); works well fantastic thank you very much. thank you all

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.