# Making text inline within a div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to make my `h1` be inline within my box like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Xa8.png). Currently my H1 text is stacked on top of each other [and looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWBtx.png). I want this to be inline rather than stacked on top of one and other, I have tried adding `display: inline-block;` and `display: inline;` to my H1 neither working. What do I need to add or remove from my H1 or box div to be able to achieve my H1 being inline!

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Centered Text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  background-color: teal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
h1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}
```

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp8t50cn/1/)

Comment: so you want this : https://jsfiddle.net/rp8t50cn/3/ ?

Comment: yes but like that rearranges my text so it is not centered in my div. I want my text to be inline will also maintaining being centered.

Comment: so you are complicating you stuff ...

Comment: Not really sure what you mean answer has been found anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Johannes since his need is to center, so the question is a perfect duplciate and he can find all what he need well commented and well explained there ... we will also find a better way than using absolute position as it's not the best way

Comment: `Not really sure what you mean answer` i simply mean that you are writing a complicated code for a an easy thing ... check above question and you will find better easier way

Comment: @TemaniAfif Still, the error is the missing `width` setting, which is not talked about in that answer

Comment: @Johannes ok you provided the solution of the width and i provided better lots of ways to center because the purpose is not only to fix issue but to also understand the need and try to provide better ways .. and i am sure your agree that we can do this easily without all this code

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block

Comment: possible duplocate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css/8865463#8865463

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `h1` has `position: absolute`, but no `width` setting. Just add `width: 100%;` to it to make it the width of its container so the texts fits into it in one line.

https://jsfiddle.net/80r16xgs/2/

Comment: Beat me to it. :P

Comment: Thank you! Will mark correct when it allows me to :)

Comment: if you insist it's not a duplicate, at least give a clear explanation of why we need width ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to `h1`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp8t50cn/4/).

Answer (score -1):

Try using `position: relative` in h1.

[You can check the result](https://jsfiddle.net/svh6jay2/)