# How align text with Angular progress bar

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I would align a text with `mat-progress-bar` component.

```
<div>
  <span class="text">{{ element.progress }}</span>
  <span>
    <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="element.progress"></mat-progress-bar>
  </span>
</div>
```

Even after using `inline-block` as CSS property progress bar stay under the texte.

How can I align the two elements in the same line without reducing `mat-progress-bar` width (keep it at 100% ) ?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4t4qz?file=app/progress-bar-determinate-example.html)

Comment: What is the result you want exactly?

Comment: Have text and progress bar on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) library:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px" fxLayoutAlign="start center" >
  <span class="text">{{ element.progress }}</span>
  <mat-progress-bar fxFlex mode="determinate" [value]="element.progress"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

[image]

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-how-align-text-with-angular-progress-bar)

**Documentation**: [Demo](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) & [Info](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation)

Answer (score 2):

take a look at my solution, hope it works for you.

```css
/** No CSS for this example */
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
}
mat-progress-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the solution from the [How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div) and [Vertically centering a div inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div) articles to achieve this behavior. These articles describe why you need them well.

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="text">{{ element.progress }}</span>
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="element.progress"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

```cs
.container {
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

mat-progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4t4qz-yhwlqw).